# Add language to LANGUAGES django/python

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

I am using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.

**How do I add en-ca Canada English to the `{{ LANGUAGES }}`?**

This is the code I have used to temporarily display the available languages, just so I can see the languages:

```
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    {{ lang }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

The only English languages in the list are:

```
('en', 'English')
('en-au', 'Australian English')
('en-gb', 'British English')
```

I am wanting to add English Canada as I must set the selected value to a language select list on the landing page.

**EDIT:**

The django docs LANGUAGES reference is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGES):

The LANGUAGES list is in the django global settings [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py):

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/) for i18n?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yes, but perhaps you could point out where in the docs  you are certain that the answer is.

Comment: From where you are getting this list `LANGUAGES` ?

Comment: @soupboy, I have edited the OP with a link to the LANGUAGES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some very strange and unknown reason, when I added the `LANGUAGES = [ ... ]` code filled with my languages to my settings.py file, the code was not recognised.

After a re-start of my pc, the issue is resolved.

I hope this does help someone.